# Execute parsed xml data as command in python

Tags: android, xml, python-2.7, ui-automation, androidviewclient

I am trying to write **a automation script in python whose steps are described in a xml document**.
but when i tried to run the parsed xml data as command in python , it is treating parsed data as string and not executing it.
I am using **xml.etree.ElementTree** to parse data from xml.

my xml code is

```
    <Setting >

        <device.startActivity name="('com.android.settings/.Settings')" />
        <device.press   name="('KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN')" />
        <vc.dump name="()" />
        <vc.findViewWithText name="('About phone')">.touch(</vc.findViewWithText>
        <device.press   name="('KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN')" />
        <device.press   name="('KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN')" />
        <vc.dump name="()" />
        <vc.findViewWithText name="('Android verion')">.getParent().getChildren()[1].getText()</vc.findViewWithText>

    </Setting>
```

and i am using following code to parse and execute it.

```
Settings = ET.ElementTree(file = configration_file_name).getroot()
length = 0
for ui_application in Settings:
        if length == len(Settings) - 2:
            break
        else:
            length +=1
        if ui_application.text != None :
                ui_application.tag+ui_application.attrib['name']+ui_application.text
        elif ui_application.attrib['name'] !=None:
            ui_application.tag + ui_application.attrib['name']
        else:
             ui_application.tag
```

**Is there any better way to achieve this task?**

Comment: May I ask why do you generate xml instead of just python?

Comment: I am trying to make my python file as generic and  specify all the apps as well as their automation steps in xml file so that  i don't have to edit my python file.

Comment: But then you'll have to map all the python language, otherwise you'll be loosing the ability of using loops, data structures, etc.

Comment: i am aware of the situation , but i am not able to find any better to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed concatenating string will just result in another string. To run string containing python codes as python expression, you need to use [`exec()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec) function, for example  :

```
....
else:
    exec(ui_application.tag)
```

or if you expect the expression to return value, you can use [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) instead of `exec()` :

```
....
else:
    result = eval(ui_application.tag)
```